# Comando SQL não funciona com o select

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

Segue meu código completo:

```
<?
    include("conectar.php");    

$query = "select * from pagseguro ORDER BY Referencia DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die();

    if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){
        $status = trataaspas($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']);
        $status_explode = explode("|", $status);        
    }

if($status_explode[0]=="aprovado"){

    $SQL = "update pagseguro set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '".$status_explode[1]."'";  

}elseif($status_explode[0]=="completo"){

    $SQL = "update pagseguro set StatusTransacao='Completo' where Referencia = '".$status_explode[1]."'";  

}elseif($status_explode[0]=="cancelado"){

    $SQL = "update pagseguro set StatusTransacao='Cancelado' where Referencia = '".$status_explode[1]."'";  

}elseif($status_explode[0]=="devolvido"){

    $SQL = "update pagseguro set StatusTransacao='Devolvido' where Referencia = '".$status_explode[1]."'";  

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function alterarStatusFunction(val){
if(val =="aprovado"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para APROVADO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="completo"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para COMPLETO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="cancelado"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para CANCELADO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="devolvido"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para DEVOLVIDO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">

<?  if(isset($total)){ if($total==0){?>
N/D
<? }else{ ?>

<tr><td>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" class="t-a">
<thead>
    <tr class="th-a"> 
    <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center" width="7%">Refer&ecirc;ncia</th>
    <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Opções</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<form name="formtransacoes" id="formtransacoes" action="" method="post">
<?
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $statustranssacao = $obj->StatusTransacao;
?>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?=$obj->Referencia;?></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
    <?  if($obj->TransacaoID!=''){?>
    <select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title);" name="alterarStatus">
        <option selected title="0">- Opções -</option>
        <option disabled="disabled">------------------------------------------</option>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Aprovado' && $statustranssacao!='Completo'){?><option title="aprovado" value="aprovado|<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como APROVADO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Completo' && $statustranssacao=='Aprovado'){?><option title="completo" value="completo|<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como COMPLETO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Cancelado'){?><option title="cancelado" value="cancelado|<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como CANCELADO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Devolvido'){?><option title="devolvido" value="devolvido|<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como DEVOLVIDO</option><? } ?>
    </select>
    <? }else{ ?>
    <span>Transação não iniciada!</span>
    <? } ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<? } } ?>       
</form>
</tbody>

<? } ?>

</table>
</td></tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer por que não funciona? Parece que ele não ta executando a query para atualizar o registro do item selecionado.

Comment: Não tem nenhum conexão com o banco no seu código nem a execução, só tem um string com o update

Comment: Ele esta no arquivo de conexão, não coloquei ele ali.

Comment: Mas falta um `mysqli_query()` ou `$pdo->query()` sem isso nenhuma instrução sql é processada.

Comment: Eu atualizei o código, da uma olhada..

Comment: hehehe é o caso de acharem que somos seres StackOverflownianos dotados de superpoderes que podem adivinhar qual é o código

Comment: removi a minha reposta que foi só pra mostrar que não há nada de errado no SQL e que estaria faltando somente a parte para execução do UPDATE, ou seja $data = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo consegui fazer funcionar, sabe alguma forma de criar uma validação para mostrar uma mensagem se foi executado a query ou não?

Comment: rapaz, eu desconfiava dessa parte, na resposta que removi eu havia comentado `Talvez na segunda parte, como estão sendo carregados os values`. Beleza que vc conseguiu. A validação pode ser bem simples `if($SQL){mensagem sucesso}else{erro}` Tem mais aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060325/need-to-test-if-sql-query-was-successful

Answer (score 2):

No código tem um seria de strings com `update` se não forem enviadas para o banco elas não fazem nada. Basicamente o que faltou no seu código foi um `mysqi_query()`.

Pode simplificar os if com um array de status.

Tome cuidado com a lógica e escopo das variáveis.

```
if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){
   $status = trataaspas($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']);
   $status_explode = explode("|", $status);

   $status = array('aprovado' => 'Aprovado', 'completo' => 'Completo', 'cancelado' => 'Cancelado', 'devolvido' => 'Devolvido');

   $statusTransacao = isset($status[$status_explode[0]]) ? $status[$status_explode[0]] : false;
   if($statusTransacao){
      $sql = sprintf("update pagseguro set StatusTransacao='%s' where Referencia = '%s'", $statusTransacao, $status_explode[1]);
      mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)); //linha que executa a sql ;)
   }
   //demais códigos...
```

Comment: O mysqi_query() estava dentro do arquivo de conexão, mas eu atualizei a pergunta com os códigos corretos, da uma olhada, mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: @CEW no código da pergunta não tem nenhum `mysqli_query()` para o update.

Comment: Eita, é verdade.. entendi o que você quis dizer. Realmente esqueci de colocar o mysqli_query para os updates.. Eu testei com seu código mas não funcionou também

Comment: @CEW deu algum erro? colocou o `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Sim, mas não ocorre nenhum erro simplesmente não executa o update. Eu não consegui entender esse novo jeito que você fez ali, ele ta pegando a ID de referência dos value?

Comment: o nome já diz tudo `trataaspas` mas como é esse código?

Comment: @CEW veja se entra no `if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){` pode colcar uns `echos ...` para verificar ou break point caso use o xdebug.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo este código naõ interfere em nada, eu testei sem ele e não funcionou.

Comment: @rray vou testar aqui, ja ja te falo. Valew ;)

Comment: @CEW  a gente tem que fuçar tudo, se tá beleza então continuar procurando

Comment: @rray não vai, coloquei um echo ali e ele não apareceu a mensagem nem do echo.. acho que deve ser algum erro no código php.

Comment: @CEW também sugiro vc extrair o código que faz o update para outro arquivo php, lembre de colocar o nome dele na action do form. Assim você separa bem o código que faz a exibição do qual faz uma alteração no banco.

Comment: @rray Eu vi que o problema esta nessa parte: `if($_REQUEST['alteraStatus']){
  $status = $_REQUEST['alteraStatus'];
  $status_explode = explode("|", $status);  
 }`

Eu testei alterando para `$status = "aprovado|12345";`, ai ele funcionou e mostrou o echo. Isso significa que ele não esta recebendo o valor das option não é isso?

Comment: Dei um `echo $_REQUEST['alteraStatus'];` na página e vi que ele ta pegando o texto só do primeiro input, e não o valor. Retornou isso: - Opções -

Comment: Primeiro option*

Comment: Consegui resolver, era o primeiro option o problema, apenas inseri o atributo disabled nele e funcionou :D